# ManagedExecutorService since 1.0?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javadoc, java-ee-7

In the javadoc of [ManagedExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html), there is

> **Since:**
>      1.0

doesn't this interface come from 
[jsr 236](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=236)
which was released in 2013?

Isn't it new for JavaEE 7?
[concurrency utilities for java ee 7](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/concurrency_utilities_for_java_ee)

What does this **since** **1.0** in javadoc mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.0 means version of the package (which is `java.enterprise.concurrent`), not the JDK itself.